# In one of Heinlein's lesser-known novels, he described an unusual ability to detect metal objects without looking at them. Which one?

Tags: story-identification, books

When I was young I had the seeming ability to "feel" metal objects in the dark, or with my eyes closed, from a spot deep in the center of my forehead behind the bridge of my nose.

Yeah, I know, weird. And I can't do it anymore, I got glasses with metal frames in 7th grade and after a year of headaches that "ability" went away.

And I never would have mentioned that to anyone, except in one of Heinlein's less-popular books, one of the protagonists describes exactly the same thing, as an odd ability nobody believes in. Nothing comes of it in the story, but it was such a dead-on description that I always just assumed that Heinlein had the same subjective experience.

I was recently discussing this, but of course I forget which novel that was in.

Comment: "Lost Legacy" involves psychic powers, but nothing about metal detection that I can find.

Comment: *Beyond This Horizon* mentions that children sometimes have limited telepathic abilities that they lose as they grow up. Oscar in *Glory Road* has an ability to "feel" where North is - he can never get lost.

Comment: @JRE you've nailed it. In *Beyond This Horizon* chapter 15: *He had noticed when he was a boy that a physical object, especially a metallic one, brought near to his forehead above the bridge of the nose seemed to produce some sort of a response inside the head, not connected, apparently, with the physiological senses.*

Comment: @JohnRennie:  I didn't remember that section.  Go ahead and make an answer of it.

Comment: I had that super power too. It used to hurt behind the bridge of my nose when things came close, even (seemingly) with my eyes closed.

Comment: Possibly relevant is the fact that magnetite (an iron oxide that is, obviously, magnetic) concentrates in the brain. https://www.pnas.org/doi/10.1073/pnas.1613349113

Comment: Is this not common? The forehead thermometers that are held an inch away set it off *intensely*.

Comment: Many Thanks, gang. Nailed it. As you can see it was a very minor mention in one of his lesser works... I'd have said that I could probably remember anything from any Heinlein book, but I blew this one.  And yeah, I think this "ability" was real, and I'll bet Heinlein had it, or why would he make up something so odd?

Answer (score 25):

[This is really JRE's ID](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/262714/in-one-of-heinleins-lesser-known-novels-he-described-an-unusual-ability-to-det/262719#comment724064_262714), but since he has handed the baton over, the book is [*Beyond This Horizon*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/540503.Beyond_This_Horizon), which as you said is by Robert A. Heinlein. The section you remember is a throwaway comment in chapter 15:

> Hamilton turned back to his work. There were various little matters to attend to. One team of researchers in particular belonged to him alone. He had noticed when he was a boy that a physical object, especially a metallic one, brought near to his forehead above the bridge of the nose seemed to produce some sort of a response inside the head, not connected, apparently, with the physiological senses. He had not thought of it for many years, until the Great Research had caused him to think of such things.

As you say nothing further develops from this.

Comment: "brought near to his forehead above the bridge of the nose seemed to produce some sort of a response inside the head" -- uhhhh, this happens to me. Has since I was a little kid. If I hold anything to the bridge of my nose a tingling buzzing feeling develops. It is, however, clearly related to my equivocation system as other people don't trigger it if my eyes are closed by my own hand will.